# How to print 1,2,3,..N , (N-1) , (N-2) on given amount of integers

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm getting stuck of the algorithm to print this number , let's say we have 11 numbers of integers and the max value of the `N` is 5 and then we have to print like this `1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1 2 3`. Can someone give me some idea or the algorithm to print this numbers

Comment: what programming language are you trying to write this in?

Comment: Provide some more examples, please. At least to me the output sequence is not really clear and somehow doesn't match the title anyway.

Comment: @Lukehey it is better using C++ , but if you can another language it's okay and I will try to understand the code

Comment: Think about this... Let's say that you pass a number through a function and the function prints it, and then decrements the number as long as the number isn't equal or less than zero. Then the function passes the number back through function again, and the process repeats.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In Java:

```
class slcal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int Nmax = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int N = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        int t = 1, k = 1;       
        while (t <= N) {
            for (; k <= Nmax && t <= N; k++, t++)
                System.out.print(k);
            for (k = Nmax - 1; k > 0 && t <= N; k--, t++)
                System.out.print(k);
            k = 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Produces:

> 1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1 2 3

Answer (score 3):

In any C-like language (C++, C#, Java, JavaScript, etc.) you can write

```
int N = 5;
for(int i = 1; i < N; i++)
{
     // Print i:
     // System.out.print(i + " "); in Java
     // Console.Write(i + " "); in C#
     // cout << i << " "; in C++
}

for (int i = N; i >= 1; i--)
{
     // Print i
}
```

Answer (score 1):

And the recursive version;

```
void printNum(int val, int max) {
    printf("%d\n", val)
    if (val < max) {
       printNum(val+1,max);
       printf("%d\n", val)
    }
}
printNum(1,5);
```

Answer (score 1):

Without branching in a single loop:

```
constexpr static const int N = 5;
for(int i = 0; i < 11; ++i)
    std::cout << (N - std::abs(i % ((N - 1) * 2) - (N - 1))) << ' ';
```

produces

> 1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1 2 3

Answer (score 0):

Some pseudo code

```
var nmax = 11
var N = 5
var i = 1
var numbersPrinted = 0
var increment = +1
While numbersPrinted <nmax
{
  if (i = N and increment = +1) or (i = 1 and increment = -1) then increment = -increment

  i = i + increment
  numbersPrinted = numbersPrinted +1
  print i
}
```